# Does kafka has an upper limit on how many consumers it can support?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I remember there is a limit on how many consumers Kafka can support, but couldn't find documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

The most consumers you can have in a single consumer group is the number of partitions in the topic being consumed.